# Driving 6 electric channels on/off and voltage (48A / 30-41V) from pi

Tags: voltage, switches, mosfet

I would like from a pi, to drive a current of 48A and regulate voltage between 30-41V (1440-1968W !). Furthermore, this current will be split into 6 input, and I would like to be able to switch on/off those 6 outputs independently.

Do you recommend any tech (MOSFET) and any (dev) board to achieve this, avoiding extensive soldering operations and designs ? Ou should I really design my own PCB and so on ?

Comment: this is not a question about the Raspberry Pi ... look at sites that deal with drones

Comment: I want to do this with a pi: in which way it si not related to pi ? Why drones ?

Comment: drones run high current electric motors

Comment: any driver board you would use for Raspberry Pi, you could also use for an arduino, or beaglebone ... that makes your question not specific to RPi

Comment: @jsotola Well that's not obvious at all and that (exactly) could be part of an answer here.